# calling webservice from jsf managed bean which returns List throws exception

Tags: java, jsf, web-services

I created a web service in java which returns List which works perfectly fine. But, when i call that webservice in my JSF managed bean it throws exception. Here is the jsf Managed bean :-

```
package beans;

import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import javax.xml.ws.WebServiceRef;
import services.Supplier;
import services.WsSupplierServiceService;

@ManagedBean(name = "SupplierBean")
@RequestScoped
public class SupplierBean {

    @WebServiceRef(wsdlLocation = "WEB-INF/wsdl/localhost_8080/ShoppingMallBL-war/wsSupplierServiceService.wsdl")
    private WsSupplierServiceService service;
    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        services.WsSupplierService port = service.getWsSupplierServicePort();

        System.out.println(port.getAll());

        //supplierList = port.getAll();
    }


    public SupplierBean() {
    }

    private List<Supplier> supplierList;

    public List<Supplier> getSupplierList() {
        return supplierList;
    }

    public void setSupplierList(List<Supplier> supplierList) {
        this.supplierList = supplierList;
    }




}
```

Here is the exception, a very weird and long exception as usual from server :-

```
   WARNING: StandardWrapperValve[wsSupplierService]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet wsSupplierService threw exception
javax.servlet.ServletException
        at org.glassfish.webservices.JAXWSServlet.doPost(JAXWSServlet.java:152)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1523)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:188)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:641)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:97)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:85)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:185)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:332)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:233)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:165)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:791)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:693)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:954)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:170)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:135)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:102)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:88)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:53)
        at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:57)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:69)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:330)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:309)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: Exception [TOPLINK-7242] (Oracle TopLink Essentials - 2.0.1 (Build b09d-fcs (12/06/2007))): oracle.toplink.essentials.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: An attempt was made to traverse a relationship using indirection that had a null Session.  This often occurs when an entity with an uninstantiated LAZY relationship is serialized and that lazy relationship is traversed after serialization.  To avoid this issue, instantiate the LAZY relationship prior to serialization.
        at oracle.toplink.essentials.exceptions.ValidationException.instantiatingValueholderWithNullSession(ValidationException.java:887)
        at oracle.toplink.essentials.internal.indirection.UnitOfWorkValueHolder.instantiate(UnitOfWorkValueHolder.java:233)
        at oracle.toplink.essentials.internal.indirection.DatabaseValueHolder.getValue(DatabaseValueHolder.java:105)
        at oracle.toplink.essentials.indirection.IndirectList.buildDelegate(IndirectList.java:208)
        at oracle.toplink.essentials.indirection.IndirectList.getDelegate(IndirectList.java:330)
        at oracle.toplink.essentials.indirection.IndirectList$1.<init>(IndirectList.java:425)
        at oracle.toplink.essentials.indirection.IndirectList.iterator(IndirectList.java:424)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.Lister$CollectionLister.iterator(Lister.java:278)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.Lister$CollectionLister.iterator(Lister.java:265)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayElementProperty.serializeListBody(ArrayElementProperty.java:129)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayERProperty.serializeBody(ArrayERProperty.java:155)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:340)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:696)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayElementNodeProperty.serializeItem(ArrayElementNodeProperty.java:65)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayElementProperty.serializeListBody(ArrayElementProperty.java:168)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayERProperty.serializeBody(ArrayERProperty.java:155)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:340)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:696)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(MarshallerImpl.java:264)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.BridgeImpl.marshal(BridgeImpl.java:100)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.api.Bridge.marshal(Bridge.java:141)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.message.jaxb.JAXBMessage.writePayloadTo(JAXBMessage.java:317)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.message.AbstractMessageImpl.writeTo(AbstractMessageImpl.java:142)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.StreamSOAPCodec.encode(StreamSOAPCodec.java:109)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.SOAPBindingCodec.encode(SOAPBindingCodec.java:278)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.encodePacket(HttpAdapter.java:380)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.access$100(HttpAdapter.java:92)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdapter.java:525)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:285)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.handle(ServletAdapter.java:143)
        at org.glassfish.webservices.JAXWSServlet.doPost(JAXWSServlet.java:147)
        ... 26 more

SEVERE: Error Rendering View[/Supplier.xhtml]
com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException: An error occurred performing resource injection on managed bean SupplierBean
        at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.invokePostConstruct(BeanBuilder.java:229)
        at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:105)
        at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:405)
        at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:267)
        at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:86)
        at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:175)
        at com.sun.faces.el.FacesCompositeELResolver.getValue(FacesCompositeELResolver.java:72)
        at com.sun.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:99)
        at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:158)
        at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:219)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:102)
        at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:190)
        at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:178)
        at javax.faces.component.UIData.getValue(UIData.java:554)
        at javax.faces.component.UIData.getDataModel(UIData.java:1248)
        at javax.faces.component.UIData.setRowIndex(UIData.java:447)
        at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.TableRenderer.encodeBegin(TableRenderer.java:81)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeBegin(UIComponentBase.java:823)
        at javax.faces.component.UIData.encodeBegin(UIData.java:937)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1611)
        at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:168)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:848)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1613)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1616)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1616)
        at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:380)
        at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:126)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:127)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:313)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1523)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:188)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:641)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:97)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:85)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:185)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:332)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:233)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:165)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:791)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:693)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:954)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:170)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:135)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:102)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:88)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:53)
        at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:57)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:69)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:330)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:309)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderException: com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Exception attempting invoke lifecycle  method public void beans.SupplierBean.init()
        at org.glassfish.faces.integration.GlassFishInjectionProvider.invokePostConstruct(GlassFishInjectionProvider.java:135)
        at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.invokePostConstruct(BeanBuilder.java:223)
        ... 54 more
Caused by: com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Exception attempting invoke lifecycle  method public void beans.SupplierBean.init()
        at org.glassfish.faces.integration.GlassFishInjectionProvider.invokeLifecycleMethod(GlassFishInjectionProvider.java:297)
        at org.glassfish.faces.integration.GlassFishInjectionProvider.invokePostConstruct(GlassFishInjectionProvider.java:210)
        at org.glassfish.faces.integration.GlassFishInjectionProvider.invokePostConstruct(GlassFishInjectionProvider.java:133)
        ... 55 more
Caused by: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.glassfish.faces.integration.GlassFishInjectionProvider.invokeLifecycleMethod(GlassFishInjectionProvider.java:280)
        ... 57 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.glassfish.faces.integration.GlassFishInjectionProvider$1.run(GlassFishInjectionProvider.java:286)
        ... 59 more
Caused by: com.sun.xml.ws.protocol.soap.MessageCreationException: Couldn't create SOAP message due to exception: XML reader error: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxEOFException: Unexpected EOF; was expecting a close tag for element <S:Body>
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,110]
        at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.SOAPBindingCodec.decode(SOAPBindingCodec.java:359)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.process(HttpTransportPipe.java:189)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.processRequest(HttpTransportPipe.java:93)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.DeferredTransportPipe.processRequest(DeferredTransportPipe.java:105)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:629)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:588)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:573)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:470)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.helper.AbstractTubeImpl.process(AbstractTubeImpl.java:112)
        at com.sun.enterprise.security.webservices.ClientSecurityPipe.processSecureRequest(ClientSecurityPipe.java:192)
        at com.sun.enterprise.security.webservices.ClientSecurityPipe.process(ClientSecurityPipe.java:180)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.helper.PipeAdapter.processRequest(PipeAdapter.java:115)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:629)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:588)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:573)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:470)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:319)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(SEIStub.java:157)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:109)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:89)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:140)
        at $Proxy253.getAll(Unknown Source)
        at beans.SupplierBean.init(SupplierBean.java:21)
        ... 64 more
Caused by: com.sun.xml.ws.streaming.XMLStreamReaderException: XML reader error: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxEOFException: Unexpected EOF; was expecting a close tag for element <S:Body>
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,110]
        at com.sun.xml.ws.streaming.XMLStreamReaderUtil.wrapException(XMLStreamReaderUtil.java:267)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.streaming.XMLStreamReaderUtil.next(XMLStreamReaderUtil.java:95)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.streaming.XMLStreamReaderUtil.nextContent(XMLStreamReaderUtil.java:110)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.streaming.XMLStreamReaderUtil.nextElementContent(XMLStreamReaderUtil.java:100)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.StreamSOAPCodec.decode(StreamSOAPCodec.java:230)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.StreamSOAPCodec.decode(StreamSOAPCodec.java:303)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.StreamSOAPCodec.decode(StreamSOAPCodec.java:129)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.SOAPBindingCodec.decode(SOAPBindingCodec.java:354)
        ... 86 more
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxEOFException: Unexpected EOF; was expecting a close tag for element <S:Body>
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,110]
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwUnexpectedEOF(StreamScanner.java:661)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromTree(BasicStreamReader.java:2730)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.next(BasicStreamReader.java:1019)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.util.xml.XMLStreamReaderFilter.next(XMLStreamReaderFilter.java:92)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.streaming.XMLStreamReaderUtil.next(XMLStreamReaderUtil.java:76)
        ... 92 more
```

Please help me :(

Comment: as the exception is from the server, you'd better provide the server code, not the client.

Comment: Hi Bozho, Thanks for your response. I found my problem. Problem was by default if we don't use FetchType it is LAZY i changed it to EAGER and it works fine :). It actually makes sense since i am working in webservice environment

Comment: then provide the answer and mark it as accepted, so that others that will eventually stumble upon the same will benefit